# Realm Error: "JS value must be of type: number"

Tags: javascript, realm

I've had a prototype of an app running great with a simple, single-scheme realm. But now I want to add a couple of other schema and let one schema contain a list of the others.

Ultimately, I get an error when executing the

```
let realm = new Realm({schema: MySchemas});
```

line. Error is: "JS value must be of type: number". Here's how I've got things setup.

**Schema.js**

```
'use strict';

let currentSchemaVersion = 0;

const Schema1 = {
    name: 'Type1',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {type: 'string', indexed:true},
        propOne: 'string',
        propTwo: 'string',
        propThree: 'int',
        propFour: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Type2'},
        propFive: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Type3'}
    }
};

const Schema2 = {
    name: 'Type2',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties:{
        id: 'string',
        prop1: 'string'
    }
};

const Schema3 = {
    name: 'Type3',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties:{
        id: {type:'string', indexed:true},
        propOne: {type:'string', indexed:true},
    }
}

export const MySchemas = [Schema1, Schema2, Schema3];
```

Then in the referencing file, call it **MyComponent.js**

```
'use strict';

import Realm from 'realm';
import * as MySchemas from './Data/Schema.js';

let realm = new Realm({schema: MySchemas}); //BARRRFFFF!
```

The only number in the whole lot is propThree from Type1, right? So I figure the problem is somehow related, but I've got no visibility into the internals so I don't know what the deal is. I've tried with and without a default on that property. Either way it's no go.

Thanks a ton for any insight. And no, unfortunately, [How to add a nested List of objects in Realm "Error: JS value must be of type: object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214973/how-to-add-a-nested-list-of-objects-in-realm-error-js-value-must-be-of-type-o) is not helpful.

Edit: I just removed the nested lists AND the only property in the whole show that was a number (propThree) and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chalk it up to being fairly new to JS, I guess. I've been able to get things working by changing how I import the schemas into MyComponent.js.

Instead of

```
import * as MySchemas from './Data/Schema.js';
```

if I go with

```
import {MySchemas} from './Data/Schema.js';
```

things work.  Alternatively, if Schema.js uses **export default**, then I believe the original import will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same error.
In my realm object.schema , i set a primaryKey "id", but when i create object, i had not assign "id" value . Because i think the primaryKey will autonomous increase, if i don't assign value .
Actually, the primaryKey will not autonomous increase, because it's property can be  "string" or "int" . In addition, the primaryKey should be unique and non-null .
So, i guess you had not assign the primaryKey's value, then suffer this error.
[Realm Error: “JS value must be of type: number”](http://www.jianshu.com/p/59be3b9879e0)